# java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.model.User error while trying to display logged in users using Spring Security and Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am very new to Spring Security and I am trying to display username of logged user. I am using Thymeleaf view.

Here is my code:

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginPage(Model model) {

        User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        String name = user.getUsername(); //get logged in username
        model.addAttribute("username", name);

        return "login";
    }
}
```

I am trying to display it like this

```
Username: <span th:text="${username}"></span>
```

I am not quite sure this is the right way to do it.

I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.model.User
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you show the full html page?

Comment: @PeriklisDouvitsas that is it I am just trying to display username

Comment: Does your code crashes on the html page or in the java? Can you put a breakpoint on the line return "login"; Does it crashes before that line?

Comment: @PeriklisDouvitsas it goes in loginPage method and then it crashes. When I run it without    `User user = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
            String name = user.getUsername(); 
            model.addAttribute("username", name);` It runs fine so I guess is something with this part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution that works for me.
My controller looks like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginPage(Model model) {
        return "login";
}
```

So it basic
and in my index.html file I have used this to display username

```
<span sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
    | Logged user: <span sec:authentication="name"></span> |
    Roles: <span sec:authentication="principal.authorities"></span> |
```

I have used basic Spring Security integration. 
Here is the useful link 
http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springsecurity.html

Hope that helps someone with same issue.

Comment: @PeriklisDouvitsas check out here.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the import to com.model.User, namely remove this line from your controller

```
import com.model.User
```

and add this import

```
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
```

In the Java code you mixed your domain class User with the User class provided from the Spring Security.

In addition, change your code to the following

```
Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
String username = null;
if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
    username = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
} else {
    username = principal.toString();
}

model.addAttribute("username", username);

return "login";
```

You can find more information here
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#obtaining-information-about-the-current-user

Comment: When I change it I got this error `java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`

Comment: @dome I have updated my answer. Check again and let me know

Comment: How should I display it in html? The username @PeriklisDouvitsas

Comment: @dome The way that you did it before. I have updated my answer. You need the following lines of code model.addAttribute("username", name);
and return "login";

Comment: Did same before I asked but like this `model.addAttribute("username", username);` but is not working this way or way you wrote it. It underlines name is red. @ PeriklisDouvitsas

Comment: @dome I Have updated my answer. I have declared username outside of the if else.

Comment: Thanks mate, but I already found solution. @PeriklisDouvitsas

Comment: @dome what was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use this to obtain the username:

```java
String name = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
```

Comment: How should I display username in html in this case? @holmis83

Comment: @dome As in your question.